# How do you call a node.js function from a HTML page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, node-modules, azureservicebus

I'm following a node.js and Azure service bus tutorial.
I'm able to run the below as a node app, however, I am struggling to call a node function from my HTML page:

Note that all the files have correctly loaded with the node http-server module, however, when I call the main function, I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: ServiceBusClient is not defined
```

Node.js function:

```
const { ServiceBusClient } = require("@azure/service-bus");

// Define connection string and related Service Bus entity names here
const connectionString ="";
const queueName = "";

async function main() {
  const sbClient = ServiceBusClient.createFromConnectionString(
    connectionString
  );
  const queueClient = sbClient.createQueueClient(queueName);
  const sender = queueClient.createSender();

  try {
    for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
      const message = {
        body: "{}",
        label: "Contact",

        userProperties: {
          myCustomPropertyName: "my custom property value",
        },
      };
      console.log(`Sending message: ${message.body}`);
      await sender.send(message);
    }

    await queueClient.close();
  } finally {
    await sbClient.close();
  }
}

main().catch((err) => {
  console.log("Error occurred: ", err);
});
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Node is backend business logic, the HTML is the front end and so there is no direct communication to the methods in Node.. You could implement some webserver like `express` to allow http calls to be made to the node server, and from there you could call your business logic..

Comment: Note: I'm not sure 100% with the ServiceBus but it seems there is a websocket interface you might look into : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/service-bus/servicebusclientoptions?view=azure-node-latest

Comment: Thank you - this was the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Summarize the comments from Pogrindis for other communities reference:

Node is backend business logic, the HTML is the front end and so there is no direct communication to the methods in Node. We could implement some webserver like `express` to allow http calls to be made to the node server, and from there we could call the business logic. And for the error of service bus, we need to implement the [ServiceBusClientOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/service-bus/servicebusclientoptions?view=azure-node-latest) interface.

Answer (score 0):

To use Azure SDK libraries on a website, you need to convert your code to work inside the browser. You can do this using bundler such as rollup, webpack, parcel, etc. Refer to this [bundling docs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/documentation/Bundling.md) to use the `@azure/service-bus` library in the browsers.

Moreover, the code in your sample looks like it is using version 1.

Version 7.0.0 has been recently published. Refer to the links below.

- [@azure/service-bus - 7.0.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/service-bus)
- [Samples for 7.0.0](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/master/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/samples)
- [Guide to migrate from @azure/service-bus v1 to v7](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/migrationguide.md)